# How do you check two conditions for current route laravel 5.7 blade template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Im trying to pass a condition with a logical OR on blade view where I can display a div tag, Whenever either of the two conditions becomes true.

```
@if(\Route::current()->getName() != 'this_route' or \Route::current()->getName() != 'other_route')
      <div>Display when is true</div>
    @endif
```

OR

```
@if(\Route::current()->getName() != 'this_route' || \Route::current()->getName() != 'other_route')
          <div>Display when is true</div>
        @endif
```

Both above codes do not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `&&` condition because as you said if both condition true then both parts should be executed then here you need to use `and` condition.

```
@if(\Route::current()->getName() != 'this_route' && \Route::current()->getName() != 'other_route')
    <div>Display when is true</div>
@endif
```